# generate dynamic record based on the record saved in the table[Oracle SQL query]. Please refer the image link to know about the requirements

Tags: sql, oracle, select, recursive-query

actual record:

[image: actual record]

expected record:

[image: expected record]

**create table and insert statements are here:-**

```
create table t11
    (
    id number,
    name varchar2(20),
    standard varchar2(20),
    sdt date
    );

insert into t11 values(1,'Ramakrushna',to_char(1,'RN'), sysdate);

insert into t11 values(1,'Ramakrushna',to_char(2,'RN'), sysdate);   

insert into t11 values(2,'Ramakrushna',to_char(1,'RN'),sysdate);

insert into t11 values(2,'Ramakrushna',to_char(5,'RN'),sysdate);

insert into t11 values(3,'Ramakrushna',to_char(1,'RN'),sysdate);
```

dynamic record are based on the id and it should generate 8 records along with id. 
record saved in the table be like, 
for id 1 record can i and iii standard(roman value), 
but expected record for id 1 will be, i,ii,iii,iv,v,vi,vii,viii, and same goes for others id also, based on record save in the table.

**here is my approach, using with as clause.** it required little modification.

```
 with t01 as (
    select rownum rn,id,name,standard,sdt from t11
    ),
    t02 as (
    select rownum rn ,id,name,to_char(to_char(l,'RN')) as standard,sdt,l
       from t01
          left outer join (select level l from dual connect by level <= ((select max(rn) from t01) + 6)) lev on 1 = 1 -- passed 2 as argument
    ),
    t03 as (
    select  t02.id,t02.name,t02.standard,t02.sdt,
    row_number() over(partition by standard order by 1) rnk
    from t02 where not exists (select 'Y' from t01 where t01.standard = t02.standard)
    )
    select id,name,standard,sdt from t03 where rnk = 1
    union
    select id,name,standard,sdt from t1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `name`  and `sdt`  are constant for each `id`, as shown in your sample data, then a simple approach is to just select the distinct tuples and generate all numbers with a recursive query:

```
with cte (id, name, standard, sdt) as (
    select distinct id, name, 1, sdt from t11
    union all
    select id, name, standard + 1, sdt from cte where standard < 8
)
select id, name, to_char(standard, 'RN') standard, sdt 
from cte
order by id, standard
```

I like to use common table expressions instead of `connect by`, because they are standard SQL and supported for quite a long time in Oraclce, but the logic would be just the same with `connect by`:

```
select distinct id, name, to_char(level, 'RN') standard, sdt 
from t11
connect by level <= 8
order by id, standard
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e6149ed543796949feab6e2a17a95be6)**:

```
ID | NAME        | STANDARD        | SDT      
-: | :---------- | :-------------- | :--------
 1 | Ramakrushna |               I | 10-JUN-20
 1 | Ramakrushna |               V | 10-JUN-20
 1 | Ramakrushna |              II | 10-JUN-20
 1 | Ramakrushna |              IV | 10-JUN-20
 1 | Ramakrushna |              VI | 10-JUN-20
 1 | Ramakrushna |             III | 10-JUN-20
 1 | Ramakrushna |             VII | 10-JUN-20
 1 | Ramakrushna |            VIII | 10-JUN-20
 2 | Ramakrushna |               I | 10-JUN-20
 2 | Ramakrushna |               V | 10-JUN-20
 2 | Ramakrushna |              II | 10-JUN-20
 2 | Ramakrushna |              IV | 10-JUN-20
 2 | Ramakrushna |              VI | 10-JUN-20
 2 | Ramakrushna |             III | 10-JUN-20
 2 | Ramakrushna |             VII | 10-JUN-20
 2 | Ramakrushna |            VIII | 10-JUN-20
 3 | Ramakrushna |               I | 10-JUN-20
 3 | Ramakrushna |               V | 10-JUN-20
 3 | Ramakrushna |              II | 10-JUN-20
 3 | Ramakrushna |              IV | 10-JUN-20
 3 | Ramakrushna |              VI | 10-JUN-20
 3 | Ramakrushna |             III | 10-JUN-20
 3 | Ramakrushna |             VII | 10-JUN-20
 3 | Ramakrushna |            VIII | 10-JUN-20
```

Comment: super solutions